# Use parent scope/methods/attributes in transcluded components

Tags: angular, scope, ng-content

I try to use transclusion n angular6 and fail to get my scopes straight.

```
<component-smart1
  [someObject]="myObject"
  [someService]="saidService">

  <component-dumb-1
    [specificObject]="getSpecificObject()"></component-dumb-1>

  <component-dumb-2
    [specificObject]="getSpecificObject()"
    (someEvent)="handleEvent()"></component-dumb-2>

</component-smart1>
```

Now i want the dumb components (`component-dumb-1`, `component-dumb-2`) to use the smart components (`component-smart1`) scope/methods/attributes.

My goal is to be able to compose different variantions with different components in the transclusion, all using the same methods from the smart components.
For instance:

```
<component-smart1
  [someObject]="myObject"
  [someService]="saidService">

  <component-dumb-1
    [specificObject]="getSpecificObject()"></component-dumb-1>

  <component-dumb-2
    [specificObject]="getSpecificObject()"
    (someEvent)="handleEvent()"></component-dumb-2>

  <component-dumb-3
    [specificObject]="getSpecificObject()"
    (someOtherEvent)="handleOtherEvent()"></component-dumb-3>

</component-smart1>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? What you want to achieve and what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think you are trying to make a kind of generic `smart-component`and want its children (via `ng-content`) to have access to its scope instead of the scope of the component were you wrote this template. This is not possible I think and a bit a misconception of what Transclusion is doing.

Smart-Component are often the very specific ones and it is okay that they are bound to a specific route and stuff. If that wouldn´t be the case you would end up in having a lot of heavy stuff (e.g. services injected) in there that is probably not needed in every specific situation.

Transclusion helps in composing dumb-components, if you design them well. So they should be as generic or flexible as possible.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in Angular >= 2.x there is no scope anymore. The execution context for a component's template is always its component class. However, there are several ways to communicate between `parent => child` and `child => parent`.

The first approach is to use the `@ContentChildren` decorator that will return a `QueryList`. This requires you to either add template reference variables, for instance `#myChild`. This is what your template would look like then:

```
<component-smart1>
  <component-dumb-1 #myDumbChild></component-dumb-1>
  <component-dumb-2 #myDumbChild></component-dumb-2>
</component-smart1>
```

Using the `@ContentChildren` decorator you can query those reference variables and access the dumb components public APIs.

Another way is to leverage the power of the DI system. For example you could configure a provider on the child component level, use an abstract class as the injection token and for the strategy `useExisting`. This will allow you to query one token to get all of your content children of a specific type. Here's an example:

```
abstract class MyDumbComponent {
  // some properties here
  // some methods here
};

@Component({
  selector: 'my-dumb-component',
  providers: [
    { provide: MyDumbComponent, useExisting: DumbComponentA }
  ]
})
export class DumbComponentA implements MyDumbComponent {
  ...
}
```

Note, I am using an abstract class for the token here, because interfaces will vanish after transpilation and second, I like to define some common "interface" for components that have the same methods.

In your parent component you could then query them like this:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class ParentSmartComponent { }
  @ContentChildren(MyDumbComponent) myDumbComponents: QueryList<MyDumbComponent>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // here you'll have access to your dumb components
  }
}
```

A third, **prefered** approach is to use `@Output`'s. While the above works fine in some cases, and if I understood you correctly, you want to communicate from the child components with the parent component. All of the above puts the parent component in the driver seat, meaning they are not really listing for some events but rather get access to the child's APIs. `@Output`'s on the other hand allow the the child to notify its parent that something has happened. The parent can then listen for this event and execute some method or task.

As mentioned, this is in most cases the prefered way to communicate between child and parent components, because it will not tightly couple your child components to the parent component and vice versa. The dumb components remain very reusable and only dispatch some events to the outside which parent components can then listen to and act accordingly.

This also allows you to compose your components however you like. You can use whatever dumb-component inside your smart component. The only requirement here is that they emit events to notify its parent.

For the sake of completeness, you could also inject your smart-component into your dumb-component. This is what it would look like:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyDumbComponent {
  constructor(private smartComponent: ParentSmartComponent) { }
}
```

However, I would also not recommend this approach because it, again, tightly couples your dumb components to your smart component. As @n-sokolowski mentioned already, content projection can be used as means to composition and your composed components should be as reusable and generic as possible.

To summarize, simply use `@Output`'s inside your dumb-component and emit specific events that parent components can then listen to.